# how to read in json file in lines

Tags: python, json

I got a json file in format like, each record is represented in lines:

```
{
 "A":0,
 "B":2
}{
 "A":3,
 "B":4
}
```

how to read it in a list?

Comment: If each JSON object were on a separate line, this would be easy. But the data format shown is tricky to handle because each object spans multiple lines, and there isn't a linebreak between the objects.

Comment: @Jaba This question isn't a duplicate of that one, since the input data of this one has multiple JSON objects joined together with no separators.

Comment: Is your data *exactly* like that, with simple string-number pairs, no nesting, and `}{` on a line by itself, with no extra whitespace?

Comment: @PM 2Ring Yes, it has been once  each json data per line . But with manul adding data and other option, it finally become this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is *exactly* in that format, we can edit it into valid JSON.

```
import json

source = '''\
{
 "A":0,
 "B":2
}{
 "A":3,
 "B":4
}{
 "C":5,
 "D":6
}
'''

fixed = '[' + source.replace('}{', '},{') + ']'
lst = json.loads(fixed)
print(lst)
```

**output**

```
[{'A': 0, 'B': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 4}, {'C': 5, 'D': 6}]
```

This relies on each record being separated by `'}{'`. If that's not the case, we can use regex to do the search & replace operation.

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
import pandas as pd

str = '{"A":0,"B":2}{"A":3,"B":4}'
list(pd.read_json(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `[` and `]` around your input and try this:

```
import json
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    print (data)
```

This code returns this line

> [{'A': 0, 'B': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 4}]

when I put this data into the file:

```
[
{
 "A":0,
 "B":2
},{
 "A":3,
 "B":4
}
]
```

If you can't edit the file data.json, you can read string from this file, add `[` and `]` around this string, and call `json.loads()`.

Update: Oh, I see that I added comma separator between JSON files. For initial input this my code doesn't work. But may be it is better to modify generator of this file? (i.e. to add comma separator)

Comment: So, let's formulate your question correctly: you have a concatenation of several JSON files in a one file, isnt't it? And you need to read all these concatenated files, and to save the data somehow. Is it true? If yes, what is the expected result for the example data from your question?

Comment: yes, thats what i want to express. but the example given by @Jaba is different in my case. I thought I should make a parsing script for the file

Comment: No, you can use existent parser. I've updated the answer.